# Stop PowerPoint from cropping images that I drag into placeholders

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I am making Master Slides in PowerPoint with place holders in a custom layout. However, when I create new slides with that layout, images I insert into the placeholders are cropped off. I want my image scaled to fit the placeholder while maintaing its proportions (it doesnt need to fill the entire placholder). I'm using PowerPoint 2007 in Windows XP.

Comment: If you press `ctrl+z` after inserting the image, it stretches it to full screen.  But can't find a way to create a **correct-dimensions** background, myself.

Answer (score 11):

The behavior is buried in the "Crop" ribbon menu.  When you place a photo in most containers in PowerPoint 2010+ (I believe, definitely 2013 and 2016), the default is to "Fill" as much container as possible, cropping stuff that doesn't fit the aspect ratio of the container.

Change to "Fit" to fit all of the image in the container at all times, leaving white space where it does not fill excess space.

Click the down arrow below "Crop" on the ribbon/toolbar, and the two selections are at the bottom.

[image: PowerPoint Crop to Fit vs Fill]

Comment: Where is that "Crop" dropdown?

Comment: "Crop" is in the "Picture Format" tab/ribbon

Answer (score 5):

Thats how picture placeholders work.
http://echosvoice.com/picture-placeholders-content/

> **Content placeholders** are pre-formatted areas where you can place 6 different types of content: text, tables, charts, SmartArt, pictures, clipart or video. (In PowerPoint 2013, instead of pictures and clipart, you have options for pictures on your system and online pictures.) A Content placeholder is the type of placeholder you see on the typical Title and Content layout.
> [image]
> When you click the Picture icon in this placeholder, PowerPoint fills the height or width of the placeholder with the entire picture. If you’re using a very vertical image and your content placeholder is very horizontal, your picture will be very small. Like this, for example:
> [image]
> But the whole picture will be there. PowerPoint won’t crop it or anything like that.
>
> Now, a **Picture placeholder** works differently. You can see Picture placeholders in action in the Picture with Caption layout. This placeholder has only one icon. It’s used only to insert images and is useless for other types of content.
> [image]
> In this particular Picture with Caption layout the Picture placeholder is pretty square. If you click that icon and insert a picture, you will see that PowerPoint fills the space with the picture – even if it must crop the picture to do so. Like this:
> [image]
> You can click the Crop button and resize or move your picture around in the placeholder. If you need specific instructions, check out the [sneaky little cropping refinements](http://www.echosvoice.com/crop-circles-in-powerpoint/) in that website's blog post.
> [image]

Comment: Is it possible to change the image placeholder into a content placeholder? Or do you have to delete it from the master and start again?

Answer (score 0):

If copying any table from word and powerpoint itself crops it, first you need to use autofit function in excel on the table and then copy it from word to Powerpoint as a picture. use picture option paste option in excel. then the whole table will be copied without any changes and self cropped